# Fetching GeoJson from MapBox

Tags: api, mapbox, geojson

Is there a way to fetch a geojson file from mapbox using a standard ajax request?

Something like:

```
var geoJson;
jQuery.get("https://mapbox.com/someurl/?dataset-id=xxx&token=xxx").success(function(data){
  geoJson = data;
  console.log(geoJson);
});
```

We currently download a geojson file and just load it in as a local script on the site and everything works fine. But come on, there has to be a way to fetch it from mapbox so we dont have to constantly update a local file. The client will never grasp this concept.

Anyone know of an API access point or something to fetch a geosjon file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Mapbox Datasets API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#list-features) to retrieve the full contents of a given dataset as a GeoJSON object.

The endpoint is:

```
GET https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/{username}/{dataset_id}/features?access_token={access_token}
```

The response is a hierarchy of [GeoJSON](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-geojson/) `Feature` objects. Most likely (or maybe always?), the top level object is a FeatureCollection.

Also, there is a [Javascript SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js) for the Mapbox API, which would allow you to write something like this:

```js
client.listFeatures('dataset-id', {}, function(err, collection) {
  // "collection" is the GeoJson data
  console.log(collection);
});
```